# includeslide returns error !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ./main.beamer.tex): unknown type of image

Tags: beamer, article, beamerarticle

I am trying to setup a lecture on beamer, for which I want to print the notes using beamerartcle. following the manual, I set up three mains:

**main.beamer.tex:**

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\input{main}
```

**main.article.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noxcolor]{beamerarticle}
\setjobnamebeamerversion{main.beamer}
\mode<article>
\input<main>
```

**main.tex**

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
% other packages
\begin{document}
\input{frames1.tex}
\input{frames2.tex}
\includeslide{unframe}
\end{document}
```

**frame1.tex**

```
some nonframe text
\begin{frame}[label=unframe}
text
\end{frame}
```

However, when I compile with pdflatex I get an error:

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Command \r invalid in math mode on input line 65.                                  

)
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   \beamer@slideunframe
l.35 }
pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ./main.beamer.tex): unknown type of image                           
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I do have some maths on the slides but the article and the presentation 
compile perfectly if I remove the includeslide command.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: first off ensure we have a full load so in main.tex what are frameS1 and frameS2 and AFRAME ?

Comment: It would be a lot easier for those trying to help if you made this into one single example instead of a lot of files.

Comment: as @dalief has mentioned the number of components is a concern as the loading sequence can be an issue e.g. you still have not given us any valid \input for frameS1 HOWEVER the most likely issue here is the use of dotted names DO NOT call a file main.beamer.tex for 2 reasons 1)beamer is a word for the job handling command so the files may erroneously be loaded instead of the commands 2) it may cause path handlers to bork as to what is relative to what. @ worst call it my_beamer.txt

Comment: I think this is a combination of multiple issues: 1) simple typo, it should be `[label=unfame]` 2) `ignorenonframetext` will ignore everything not in frames, such as `\input{}` -> can you move your frames directly into `main.tex`? 3) `\includeslide should only be used in the article version, so maybe something like ` \includeslide<presentation:0>{unframe}` ?

Comment: This is really a catch-22 situation. One can force beamer to not ignore the `\input` commands, but then the `ignorenonframetext` option won't work for the content of the included files. -> I would move the frames into main.tex

Comment: Ignore my point 3) in my second to last comment, that was nonsense

Answer (score 1):

thankyou for the suggestions! and sorry for delaying on reading them all. I have been a little busy at work and home.

your suggestions on the number of files involved are on the track. However, the most important thing to have into account here is the actual order in which things are compiled. suppose the following setup:

**beam.tex** contains the configs for the actual presentation. it contains a line `\input{main}`
**notes.tex** contains the configs for the beamerarticle. also contains `\input{main}`. and, it **has** to contain the line `\setjobnamebeamerversion{beam}`
**main.tex**, inputs the frames contained in their own files (frames1.tex, etc).
**frame1.tex** is the file containing the first frame and the article text. in the article text, the `\includeslide` command is called.

the label given as argument to `\includeslide` is processed from the beam.out file. than means that you need to compile the beam.tex before compiling the notes.tex.

Hence, the correct makefile should look something like this:

```
beam: beam.tex main.tex frames*.tex
         pdflatex beam.tex
         pdflatex beam.tex

notes: beam notes.tex main.tex frames*.tex
         pdflatex notes.tex
         pdflatex notes.tex
```

again , thanks for the suggestions! hope thisis usefull for someone.

now,
**main.tex